# When the Impossible becomes Possible again

Tags: math-history, fake-proofs

Many times mathematicians draw proofs about the impossibility of something. As an example, take the Abel–Ruffini theorem, which states no generic formula exists for quintic equations (I know the proof is more contrived that this).

Some "proofs" might be wrong though: maybe a formalism was overlooked... maybe there was a failed axiom. What I want to know is examples of once claimed proofs on the "impossibility" of something, but which later were revealed wrong?

Comment: If a proof contains a mistake, it won't take mathematicians long to spot it. If a proof is sound, it will remain eternally true within its set of axioms. This is one of the beauties of Mathematics.

Comment: Hence... Are there examples of something that was kept too long before someone spotted it? :-)

Comment: @AymanHourieh Not always true - see my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps one of the most famous is [Cantor's $1887$ "proof"](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/20117309?uid=3739696&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=47698975614357) of the impossibility of infinitesimals. This was presented in a letter to Weierstrass. The "proof" was later elaborated by Peano $(1892)$ and Russell $(1903)$ in their arguments against infinitesimals. Of course, nowadays, we know perfectly rigorous presentations of infinitesimals thanks to the groundbreaking work of Abraham Robinson (nonstandard analysis), as well as alternative approaches such as Synthetic Differential Geometry (which employs nilpotent infinitesimals).

Comment: I have heard this proof used as a cautionary example. Since all those involved were already convinced that infinitesimals could not exist, they were unable to recognize their own (and others') errors.

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia has a list of proofs that were later shown to be false or incomplete: [List of incomplete proofs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_incomplete_proofs)